# Launch4j only 32-bit wrapper?

Tags: java, wrapper

I wrapped my jar file successfully by launch4j and bundled it with the 64-bit JRE because I'm working on Windows 10 64-bit. The program starts without any problems - so far so well.
But I'm wondering a bit because if I look in the task manager I will see "MyProgramName (32-bit)". So launch4j only creates 32-bit exe? Makes it then sense to bundle with 64-bit JRE if the launcher is only 32-bit?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue .. any news?

Comment: Unfortunately I found no solution. It seems to be a bug in launch4j.